# Druid can not see/read GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS defined on env path

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, druid

I installed apache-druid-0.22.1 as a cluster (master, data and query nodes) and enabled “druid-google-extensions” by adding it to the array druid.extensions.loadList in common.runtime.properties.
Finally I defined GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ( which has the value of service account json as defined in https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production )as an environment variable of user that run the druid services.
However, I got the following error when I try to ingest data from GCR buckets:

> Error: Cannot construct instance of
> org.apache.druid.data.input.google.GoogleCloudStorageInputSource,
> problem: Unable to provision, see the following errors: 1) Error in
> custom provider, java.io.IOException: The Application Default
> Credentials are not available. They are available if running on Google
> App Engine, Google Compute Engine, or Google Cloud Shell. Otherwise,
> the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be
> defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See
> https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
> for more information. at
> org.apache.druid.common.gcp.GcpModule.getHttpRequestInitializer(GcpModule.java:60)
> (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule ->
> org.apache.druid.common.gcp.GcpModule) at
> org.apache.druid.common.gcp.GcpModule.getHttpRequestInitializer(GcpModule.java:60)
> (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule ->
> org.apache.druid.common.gcp.GcpModule) while locating
> com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer for the 3rd
> parameter of
> org.apache.druid.storage.google.GoogleStorageDruidModule.getGoogleStorage(GoogleStorageDruidModule.java:114)
> at
> org.apache.druid.storage.google.GoogleStorageDruidModule.getGoogleStorage(GoogleStorageDruidModule.java:114)
> (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule ->
> org.apache.druid.storage.google.GoogleStorageDruidModule) while
> locating org.apache.druid.storage.google.GoogleStorage 1 error at
> [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1,
> column: 180] (through reference chain:
> org.apache.druid.indexing.overlord.sampler.IndexTaskSamplerSpec["spec"]->org.apache.druid.indexing.common.task.IndexTask$IndexIngestionSpec["ioConfig"]->org.apache.druid.indexing.common.task.IndexTask$IndexIOConfig["inputSource"])
> A case reported on this matter caught my attention. But I can not see
> any verified solution to that case. Please help me.

We want to take data from GCP to on prem Druid. We don’t want to take cluster in GCP. So that we want solve this problem.

Comment: You must ensure the ENV is accessible via JVM. Are you running druid as a systemctl service?

Comment: Yes. I am running druid as a systemctl service.

Comment: Try adding GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with its value inside your systemctl unit file, and then see if it works.

Comment: We try this but this is not working :( Have got any example for this?

Comment: We add GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for correct type in systemctl and we solve this problem. We try 3 days to solve this problem :( Thanks for your helping Mostafa @MostafaTalebi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future visitors:

If you run Druid by `systemctl` you then need to add required environments in service file of systemctl, to ensure it is always delivered to druid regardless of user or environment changes.

Answer (score 1):

You must define the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` that points to a file path, and not contain the file content.

In a cluster (like Kubernetes), it's usual to mount a volume with the file in it, and to se the env var to point to that volume.

Comment: We define this but we get error and finally we get error ingestion to Hadoop. Error in custom provider, java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running on Google App Engine, Google Compute Engine, or Google Cloud Shell. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

Have you got any example?

Comment: I solve problem. I add environments to systemctl file but correct type. Thanks for helping.